# Apache serve static content according to hostname

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, rewrite

I have tomcat running behind apache and some web application running on it.
My application handles whitelabeling so if some user will goes to
subnet1.myhost.com he will se some website and
subnet2.myhost.com he should see some another website

As part of solution, apache should handle css requests and redirect it to proper locations
so if client app from subnet1.myhost.com requests /styles/main.css apache should redirect it according to hostname so it will be /subnet1/styles/main.css
How can I configure such behavior?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single VirtualHost, you can do it with mod_rewrite:

```
<VirtualHost :80>
   ServerName *.myhost.com

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.myhost\.com
   RewriteRule ^/styles/(.*)$ /%1/styles/$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Your document root must have the following structure:

```
subnet1
   styles
       file1.css
       file2.css
subnet2
   styles
       file1.css
       file2.css
other_files_shared_across_domains
```

And your css URL should look like:

```
http://subnet1.myhost.com/styles/file1.css
http://subnet1.myhost.com/styles/file2.css

http://subnet2.myhost.com/styles/file1.css
http://subnet2.myhost.com/styles/file2.css
```

To add new subdomains, simply add new folders to the DocumentRoot folder

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done by having a different VirtualHost block for each custom site.  E.g.

```
<VirtualHost :80>
  ServerName subnet1.myhost.com

  Alias /styles /subnet1/styles

  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The `...` represents the same keywords in each block that forwards to Tomcat.  You could include a file here.

Under Debian or Ubuntu you would put each of these blocks in its own file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.  For Ubuntu 12.04 or earlier the files don't have a `.conf` extension, but for more recent Ubuntu releases they do.

Then you run `sudo a2ensite subnet1.myhost.com` to enable the site.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
Can I configure it in generic way so I wouldn't change my configuration every time I add new subdomain?